# JQuery hide/show not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to make a drop down menu and have it open sub menus on click and close them on click, but I cannot even get it to hide my submenu to start off with on a click.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#timeli").click(function(){
        $("#timeUlSub").hide();
    });});
```

And this is my html code that I am trying to get to hide/show

```
<div class="timeline">
            <ul>
                <li id="timeli">1996
                    <ul id="timeUlSub">
                        <li>
                            <p class="timeline-date">1997</p>
                            <p class="timeline-description">This is in the submenu</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>1999</li>
                <li>2000</li>
                <li>2004</li>
                <li>2006</li>
                <li>2007</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Am I doing something wrong on the jquery end? Because from what I have looked on here this should be working, but it's not.

Comment: Code looks okay. Are you sure you have `jQuery` loaded? Console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) may be more effective:

```
    $("#timeli").click(function(){
        $("#timeUlSub").toggle();
    });
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04y4dm06/3/)**

Comment: Thank you i knew the toggle was a better method i just was trying to get it to hide since it was not doing anything when i click on it with toggle on. I had the library improperly referenced.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#timeli").on('click', function()
          {
              $("#timeUlSub").toggle();          
          });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline">
            <ul>
                <li id="timeli">1996
                    <ul id="timeUlSub">
                        <li>
                            <p class="timeline-date">1997</p>
                            <p class="timeline-description">This is in the submenu</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>1999</li>
                <li>2000</li>
                <li>2004</li>
                <li>2006</li>
                <li>2007</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you i just had the Jquery not linked properly that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`#timeUlSub` is part of the `#timeli li`. Move it outside the `li`. In addition, jquery `.slideToggle()` is a better method than `.hide()`.

Check if you have Jquery linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for conditional usage :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#timeli").on('click', function(){
        if($("#timeUlSub").is(':hidden')){
           $("#timeUlSub").show();  
        } else {
           $("#timeUlSub").hide();  
        }  
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="timeline">
     <ul>
         <li id="timeli">1996
         <ul id="timeUlSub">
            <li>
               <p class="timeline-date">1997</p>
               <p class="timeline-description">This is in the submenu</p>   
            </li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li>1999</li>
         <li>2000</li>
         <li>2004</li>
         <li>2006</li>
         <li>2007</li>
   </ul>
</div>

#timeUlSub{
        display:none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#timeli").click(function(){
        $("#timeUlSub").toggle();
});});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shellyjindal/rxb56emp/